# Starting service using custom action in Android library project

Tags: android, android-service, android-library

I had created one **Android Library Project named MyLibrary** which has following **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.myservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name="mytest.myservice.RemoteService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="MYSERVICE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After Creating Library project I added the reference of **this library project to my application named TestMyLibrayApp**.I am starting service from **My application** as follows.

```
Intent playerservice = new Intent();
playerservice.setAction("MYSERVICE");
getBaseContext().bindService(playerservice,conn , Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Where **conn** is the service connection object.
Now the problem is Serivce is not starting.Can anyone suggest where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `<service>` section to TestMyLibraryApp's manifest. The library's manifest is not used.

Comment: If it is not using library project manifest then what is the use of making a library project?

Comment: But the problem which ever app want to use my library project compulsorily declare the service in there manifest.... am I right?

Comment: Correct. Manifest files are not carried over from library projects.

Comment: But why can't this Service be declared in the library project's Manifest??